# Node.JS/NPM Installation on Plesk 17

Tags: node.js, plesk, plesk-onyx

I have followed following Installation manual for Node.js on Plesk Onyx and activated node.js for my domain. But I am only able to RestartApp or Disable Node.js.
https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/nodejs-support.76652/

Now I am beeing asked for my Application Startup File... Well I do not have a Node.js application yet thats why I installed it in the first place in order to make one.

I cant install NPM either because well... I dont have a Application...

Even when login in with SSH and using "node -v" I will just get a error saying "-bash: node: command not found".

So how am I supossed to develop with Node.js on Plesk if it clearly does not install Node.js properly or let me install a package manager like NPM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once the [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) file created in the application root directory, **NPM install** and **Run script** buttons will appear, allowing to install specified packages or execute the predefined installation script.
Refer to this page to get the general idea regarding it - https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

The executables for node.js provided by Plesk can be found in `/opt/plesk/node/<version>/bin/`. For example:

```
# /opt/plesk/node/6/bin/node -v
v6.12.2
# /opt/plesk/node/6/bin/npm -v
3.10.10
```

You can add it to PATH variable to run it without specifying the full path:

```
# export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/6/bin:$PATH
# echo "export PATH=/opt/plesk/node/6/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc
# node -v
v6.12.2
```